# When do you need to deploy the same contract multiple times on the same network?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

When do you need to deploy the same contract multiple times on the same network?

While there are posts that say 'how', but why and when do we need to do so in the first place? Please exemplify. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you consider it necessary.

For example a very famous project requires wallet contracts to interact with their main contract, so for every user a wallet contract is created. All the wallet contracts are exactly the same, only the "owner" is different.

A famous payment provider has a solutions where a customer deploys a thin proxy contract to accept payments that forward every deposit to a central contract. The proxy address is used to identify which customer is receiving the deposit.

In some circumstances it is useful, and in other it is not. It depends on the problem you want to solve.